# Can I share remote drive to local machine using Windows Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I know that using Windows Remote Desktop, I can share local drive to the remote desktop session.

Is it possible the opposite, i.e. use Windows Remote Desktop to see the remote drive mounted on my local machine?

Both machines run Windows 10.